# Grid-Items(default Buttons) increase the grid-container?

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have a flex-container with 2 flex-items.

```
<div className="flexContainer">
  <div className="FlexItem1"></div>
  <div className="FlexItem2"></div>
</div>
```

Both flex items have:

```
flex-grow: 1;
```

[image]

flex item 2 is:

```
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

Now I add grid items into grid container(grid items = default buttons).

Problem:
These grid items increasing the width of the grid container.

[image]

Questions:
Why are the default grid items increasing the width of its container here?
What is the best way to ensure the flex items stay 50-50 in width, regardless of what happens inside the flex items?

Comment: use the full setup :   `flex:1 0 50%;` *(+ box-sizing reset)* or shorthand : `flex:1 ;` flex-grow on its own is not enough, it still can shrink ;)  Demo : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWaQKpE

Comment: That works! I gonna dive deeper in that full setup, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Use flex-basis for your inner containers and set buttons width/height 50px/50px**

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
}
.FlexItem1,.FlexItem2 {
  flex-basis: 150px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.FlexItem2 {
  border-left: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.FlexItem2 button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="FlexItem1"></div>
  <div class="FlexItem2">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```